# Checking if a user exists with mongodb and passport.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

I am using mongoose and passport-local for my strategy. With Redux I dispatch an action to register a user and it works fine. After I register I want to use those same credentials to log the user in.

I have login working with JWT but it's not hitting any backend, only a users object. I'm wondering how I can use passport to authenticate with my mongo backend, give a success response, and then I can keep using my current setup to issue the JWT. I know I can probably rework this to be cleaner and use passport only but I have this working so far and I'd like to only connect it to a real database now that `registerUser` successfully uses.

**./server/models/account.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Account = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

**./index.js** (server entry point)

```
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser')

// db
var db            = require('./server/db'); // just db url
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var passport      = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var Account       = require('./server/models/account');

var app = new (require('express'))()
var port = 3000

// webpack stuff went here

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html')
})

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
mongoose.connect(db.url);

app.use(require('./server/routes')); <------------------------------ file below

app.listen etc
```

**./server/routes.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    _       = require('lodash'),
    config  = require('./config'),
    jwt     = require('jsonwebtoken');

var app = module.exports = express.Router();

// XXX: This should be a database of users :).
var users = [{                    <----------------------------dummy account
  id: 1,
  username: 'test',
  password: 'test'
}];
function createToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign(_.omit(user, 'password'), config.secret, { expiresIn: 60*60*5 });
}
function getUserScheme(req) {
  var username;
  var type;
  var userSearch = {};
  -- error stuff --
  return {
    username: username,
    type: type,
    userSearch: userSearch
  }
}

app.post('/sessions/create', function(req, res) {
  var userScheme = getUserScheme(req);
  -- error stuff --
  res.status(201).send({
    id_token: createToken(user)
  });
});
```

**./client/actions/index.js** - actions that get called to register/login (register works with mongo, login only works with a dummy object)

```
export function registerUser(creds) {
  let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `username=${creds.username}&password=${creds.password}`
  }
  return dispatch => {
    // dispatch(requestLogin(creds))
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', config)
      .then((response) =>  {
        if (!response.ok) { console.log("err"); }
        else { dispatch(loginUser(creds)) }
      }).catch(err => console.log("Error: ", err))
  }
}
// Calls the API to get a token and
// dispatches actions along the way
export function loginUser(creds) {
  let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `username=${creds.username}&password=${creds.password}`
  }
  return dispatch => {
    // We dispatch requestLogin to kickoff the call to the API
    // console.log(creds)
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds))
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/sessions/create', config)
      .then(response =>
        response.json()
          .then(user => ({ user, response }))
      )
      .then(({ user, response }) =>  {
        if (!response.ok) {
          // If there was a problem, we want to
          // dispatch the error condition
          dispatch(loginError(user.message))
          return Promise.reject(user)
        }
        else {
          // If login was successful, set the token in local storage
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.id_token)
          // Dispatch the success action
          dispatch(receiveLogin(user))
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log("Error: ", err))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like:

```
export const passportJWT = function (passport) {
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
    secretOrKey: config.JwtSecret,
  }, (jwtPayload, done) => {
  Account.findOne({ username: jwtPayload.username}, (err, account) => {
    if (err) return done(err, false);
    if (user) {
      return done(null, account);
    }
    return done(null, false);
  });
 }));
};
```

and

```
export const JWTAuthentication = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })(req, res, next);
};
```

then use this middleware for the routes that needs JWT authentication.
like:

```
yourRouter.get('/login', JWTAuthentication, (req, res) => {
  //if jwt authentication passed
  //you can access user object as req.user
});
```